# how to add_action callback for parent method?

Tags: wordpress

when we want to do add_action inside a class we usually do like this:

```
 class Myclassprefix_Some_Class extends Some_Class {
   function __construct(){
     add_action('wp_head', array($this, 'myfuncprefix_add_meta_tag'));
   }
   function myfuncprefix_add_meta_tag(){
     echo '<meta name="description" content="This is an example meta tag" />';
   }
 }
```

Now I want to call the parent method instead.

I want to change:

```
add_action('wp_head', array($this, 'myfuncprefix_add_meta_tag'));
```

to:

```
add_action('wp_head', array($parent, 'some_parent_method'));
```

How to change $parent correctly? I know I can do like this:

```
add_action('wp_head', array($this, 'some_parent_method'));
   function some_parent_method(){
     parent::some_parent_method();
   }
```

Is there any other way to do this without writing the function to call parent function?

Answer (score 0):

You can call parent class method without writing a new function to do that. The only requirement is that parent class method is defined as public.

```
class ParentClass {
    public function someMethod() {
        print('Hi'); 
    }
}

class ChildClass extends ParentClass {
    public function __construct() {
        add_action('wp_head', [ $this, 'someMethod']);
    }
}
```